# Append dataframe in pandas alternatives

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, append

I want to append a dataframe into an other but .append() doesnt work anymore

I tried to do

`combined_df.append(df, ignore_index=True)`

But it doesnt work.
I also tried .concat() but it didnt work neither stating
"AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'concat'"

Since the "df" dataframe is in a function, it changes every time the function is called and I'd like to know if there was an alternative (just like the .append() with list but for dataframes)

Comment: `concat` works fine - `df3 = pd.concat([df1,df2], ignore_index = True)`. It is worth looking at the docs to get the syntax correct.